# Wordpress: Images not displaying using for each loop

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am saving image path in database. And want to display images through foreach loop. When I use `<img src="http://localhost/uploads/imgname.jpg"  />`, its working
When I use `<img src="http://localhost/uploads/{{$t->pic}}"  />`, its not working. Though this code worked fine in laravel yet its not working in wordpress. Your kind response and help would be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
        foreach($tboxteam as  $t){
            $ename=$t->name; 
            $edesignation=$t->designation;
            $edescription=$t->description;
?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <img src="http://localhost/uploads/{{$t->pic}}"  /></td>    
                    <li><h3><?php echo $ename; ?></h3></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $edesignation; ?></h4></li>

                </ul>
                    <p><?php echo $edescription; ?></p>             
            </div>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: is $t contains pic?

Comment: do print_r($tboxteam);

Comment: $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'tboxteam';
$tboxteam=$wpdb->get_results("Select name, designation, description from $tablename");

Comment: so where is pic in query??????

Comment: Thanku sir the error has been resolved thanks a lot for your kind time

Comment: what is  the error????

Comment: <?php echo $t->pic; ?> this has been working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `file_exists` function before you call any file.

```
<?php 
$image = 'default.png';
if(file_exists('http://localhost/uploads/'.$t->pic)) {
  $image = $t->pic;
} ?>

<img src="http://localhost/uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>"  />
```